# If I have Schengen visa can I get Macedonian visa in airport

Tags: visas, macedonia, kyrgyz-citizens

I will have one business trip to Macedonia and will open Schengen visa for 1 year. Can I have Macedonian visa right in Macedonian airport? (I am not from Schengen zone)

Comment: What is your country of citizenship?

Comment: Kyrgyzstan (Central Asia)

Comment: You do not get a visa at the Airport - because you have a Schengen visa, you don't Need a Macedonian visa, as per the information in the answer

Answer (score 8):

Timatic has [information for Kyrgyzstan nationals traveling to Macedonia](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=KG&DE=SKP&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX):

> Passport required.
>
> - Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be   valid for a minimum of 90 days from the arrival date.
>
> Visa required, except for Passengers with a double or multiple entry C
>   visa issued by a Schengen Member State For details, click here. The
>   visa must be valid for all Schengen Member States and be valid for at
>   least 5 days beyond the period of intended stay in Macedonia (FYROM).
>   They are visa exempt for a maximum stay of 15 days. (SEE NOTE 52764)
>
> NOTE 52764: The max. stay is granted within 6 months.

Note also that a return/onward ticket is required. For reference, here is [Macedonia's full set of visa information](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&SECTION=VI&COUNTRY=MK&SUBSECTION=00&ExpertMode22=&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX) in Timatic.