# Do Macedonian citizens need visas to travel to Kyrgyzstan?

Tags: visas, kyrgyzstan, macedonian-citizens

I am Macedonian citizen to travel to Kyrgyzstan. Do I need a visa?

Comment: You should meet [this user](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78751/if-i-have-schengen-visa-can-i-get-macedonian-visa-in-airport/78752#78752), who had the opposite question yesterday!

Answer (score 2):

[Timatic says](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=MK&DE=FRU&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX):

> Visa Issuance: Visa required, except for Nationals of Macedonia
>   (FYROM) can obtain a visa on arrival for a max. stay of 1 month. Fee: varies
>   between USD 40.- and USD 100.-.

That would seem to say you can get a visa on arrival (assuming your trip is less than a month) upon payment of a fee, at least if you fly into Manas International Airport. While Timatic is an authoritative source (it's the database the airlines use to confirm visa requirements), I'd prefer something with a little more clarity, especially given the wide range of the fee there.

[Wikipedia agrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Kyrgyzstan#Visa_on_arrival), also citing Timatic.

The site caravanistan.com also has [some information](http://caravanistan.com/visa/kyrgyzstan/) on the process (under "visa types"):

> Kyrgyzstan visa on arrival
>
> It is possible to get the Kyrgyzstan visa on arrival only in Bishkek’s
>   Manas airport, not at a land border. It’s the same idea as before: if
>   you need a letter of invitation, you will need one for the VOA too.
>   It’s 60$ for a single entry 30 day tourist visa, 70$ for double entry
>   30 day tourist visa on arrival. It is not possible to get more than 1
>   month at the airport. It is also possible to get a business visa on
>   arrival at Manas airport. If this type of visa is extendable is an
>   open question, please inform us if you know!

Lastly, the Kyrgyzstan Embassy in Washington DC has [some relevant information](http://www.kgembassy.org/en/consular-issues/applying-for-a-visa/general-visa-information/) on their website. According to them, it appears you must enter through Manas airport and pay the visa fee in cash to get a visa on arrival.

Comment: That first Timatic quote makes it sound like *only* FYROM citizens be eligible for the VOA. Glad Wikipedia actually states *countries* ;)

Comment: @Jan Yeah it's a touch unclear. That's how Timatic is formatted. It states the general rule (visa required), then "exception for nationals of X." The full visa info for Kyrgyzstan [is here](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&SECTION=VI&COUNTRY=KG&SUBSECTION=00&ExpertMode22=&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), and then it slices and dices it in various ways.

Answer (score 1):

Although applying for EU membership I'm afraid Macedonia has not yet been admitted hence you do not qualify for visa-free entry as an EU citizen. There has been talk of withdrawal of visa-free entry regardless of citizenship.

However you are a citizen of one of the countries listed by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Kyrgyzstan) as eligible to obtain a visa on arrival at Manas International Airport valid for a maximum stay of 30 days. Yes, you do require a visa.

Answer (score 1):

As a Macedonian passport holder, you are eligible for a visa on arrival, called a Facilitated Visa, according to the [Embassy of the Krygyz Republic](http://www.kgembassy.org/en/consular-issues/applying-for-a-visa/general-visa-information/) (in Canada and the USA).